# Извлечение данных из лог файла

Tags: python, логирование

Чтобы не проверять всю статистику и не ломать глаза глядя на лог файл, я решил написать небольшой скрипт, который вытаскивает из всего лога, только нужные мне пункты статистики.
Вопрос:
Как выделить из всего лога нужные мне пункты полностью?

Пример маленького кусочка лога:

```
Scenario statistics:

Total scenarios attempted:                2
Total scenarios succeeded:                2
Total scenarios failed   :                0
Total scenarios aborted  :                0
TCP (over IPv4) throughput statistics: Port 0
rx packets ok:             490022
rx header bytes ok:        800456
rx data bytes ok:          656691968
rx packets duplicate:      0
rx header bytes duplicate: 0
rx data bytes duplicate:   0
```

Как сделать так, чтобы указав в скрипте "Scenario Statistics", он вывел мне всё, что принадлежит этому пункту до "Total scenarios aborted", а не указывать имя каждой строки отдельно, которую мне нужно вывести?

Как это сделал я сейчас в переменной `phrases`:

```
#path to logfile with statistics test
file_name = r"/home/andrey/logfile.log"
var = []
#templates by which the script outputs information to another file
phrases = ["Scenario statistics",
       "Total scenarios attempted",
       "Total scenarios succeeded",
       "Total scenarios failed",
       "Total scenarios aborted" ]

with open(file_name) as f:
    f = f.readlines()

for line in f:
    for phrase in phrases:
        if phrase in line:
            var.append(line)
            break

#I make a line from the list to write to a file
myString = '__'.join(var)

output_file = open('/home/andrey/output.txt', 'w')
output_file.write(myString)
```

Я знаю, что это ужасный костыль, просто делаю только первые шаги в этом.

Comment: Конечный автомат. Если встречена строка "Scenario statistics:" - начинать вывод строк. Если встречена "Total scenarios aborted" - заканчивать.

Comment: Используйте `sed`. `sed  -e '/match1/,/match2/!d' file.txt`

Comment: Человек спрашивает про python, это означает что он ждет ответ на python. А так способов масса как можно решить данную задачу.

Comment: чтобы блоки между заданными строками забрать (в этом случае между "Scenario Statistics" и "Total scenarios aborted"), [можно flip-flop оператор использовать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/832231/23044)

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("logfile.log") as log, open('output.txt', 'w') as output:
    write = False
    for line in log:
        if write:
            output.write(line)
            if line.startswith("Total scenarios aborted"):
                break
        else: write = line == 'Scenario statistics:\n'
```

Comment: А где тут остановка после определенной строки ?

Comment: мне кажется, как сделать выход из цикла - это очевидно

Comment: что значит очевидно. Автор написал что делает "первые шаги" и ему не  понятно. По этому человеку надо объяснить, а не так что бы он додумывал. Странный ты человек поставил дизлайк на работающее решение. Мда, нужно признавать свои ошибки тем более когда работаешь в IT сфере.

Comment: ты главное не расстраивайся сильно :)

Comment: и про "первые шаги", в вашем ответе кроме кода нет ни одного объяснения как это работает. Поэтому странно слышать такие претензии от вас :)

Comment: Ну зато у меня "выхлоп" тот который ожидает пользователь, а у вас нет )))

Answer (score -1):

```
#path to logfile with statistics test
import re

file_name = r"/home/andrey/logfile.log"
stop_line = re.compile(r'aborted')

with open(file_name) as r:
    with open('/home/andrey/output.txt', 'w') as w:
        for i in r:
            w.write('{}\n'.format(i.strip()))
            if stop_line.findall(i):
                break;
```

Comment: автор просил только нужные пункты статистики. В текущей реализации, если между Total scenario строками, будут другие, "ненужные строки", то попадут и они.

Comment: он вывел мне ВСЁ, что принадлежит этому пункту до "Total scenarios aborted",  Карл слово ВСЁ

Comment: бомбануло :) Ну еще, скрипт выводит не до строки содержащей "Total scenarios aborted", а до любой строки, содержащей "aborted". Использование регулярок для проверки нахождения подстроки в строке, это тоже не камильфо

Comment: Рега может и не лучший вариант, но в данной ситуации название полей статичны, меняются только значения. Так что данный вариант самое то ))).

Comment: Увидел, что вы бездумно наставили минусов во всех подряд ответах )) И решил еще раз глянуть ваш ответ :) В вывод попадает вообще все(до строки "Scenario statistics:"), с самого начала лога до любой строки, содержащей "aborted". Еще рас посмеялся с ваших каментов

Comment: @vadimvaduxa 
Спасибо вам большое,  дали большую почву для размышлений!)

Comment: @linuxoid69 аналогично, спасибо за ваше решение, задумался о том как всё это упростить и из двух лог файлов всё выводить в один ,для сравнения.