# Парсинг файла с помощью питона: чтение блока ограниченного заданными строками

Tags: python-3.x, парсер

есть текстовый файл:

```
Ненужный текст
Part 1
A1
Kh A
A4
H6
Part 0
Ненужный текст
```

Каким образом с помощью питона можно прочесть только те строки которые заключены в блок Part 1...Part 0

Т.е. я хочу получить:

```
А1 
Kh A
А4
Н6
```

Comment: У вас трудности с чтением текстового файла?

Comment: Нет, прочесть его полностью я могу, а вот выделить из него только данный блок текста не знаю как

Comment: А каким образом вы выделяете этот текст без питона, используя только глаза и ручку с бумажкой? Подумайте и реализуйте тот же самый алгоритм.

Comment: Читаете построчно, сравниваете содержимое каждой строки с `Part 1`, после того, как нашли эту строку, начинаете все последующие строки складывать в какую-то структуру данных, проверяя каждую строку на равенство `Part 0`. Как только нашли `Part 0`, прекращаете чтение.

Comment: обратная задача: [удалить блоки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/758726/23044)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы эмулировать [flip-flop оператор](https://habrahabr.ru/post/87272/):

```
$ perl -ne 'print if /^Part 1$/../^Part 0$/'
```

[Пример (c границами)](https://ideone.com/dw8oHt) на Питоне можно регулярные выражения использовать, чтобы блоки найти в тексте (как range regex в awk):

```
import re

blocks = re.findall(r'(?sm)^Part 1$(.*?)^Part 0$', text)
```

[Пример (без границ)](https://ideone.com/3MiaWY):

```
A1
Kh A
A4
H6
```

Можно построчно ввод прочитать, не загружая весь файл в память одновременно:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Exclusive flip-flop operator."""
import fileinput

START, END = 'Part 1', 'Part 0'
inblock = False
for line in fileinput.input():
    line = line.rstrip()
    if inblock:
       if line == END:
           inblock = False
       else:
           print(line)
    elif line == START: # not in block
       inblock = True
```

[Пример](https://ideone.com/u5ASqM).